# How to add a image into stringlist?

Tags: qt4.7

I am in need to add a image into a string list that contains item which is parsed value. Whether can i add an image in-between two strings in qt??
 Here is my sample code that i used and tried to add an image!!!

```
   myImage(://image.png);
   strList << sender + myImage + "\n" + Receiver
```

myImage is the place where i need to add the image.. Is this possible in QT? 
strlist is the QStringList which i have declared.
I am not getting the image when i run them.
Please find me a solution for this!!!!

Thanks in Advance and Regards,
Naufal.A

Comment: Please anyone help me in this

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the myImage is of type QImage. In that case what you doing is illegal to start from. Add the url of the image (as u have ://image)

Answer (score 0):

QStringList is a typedef for QList - it means it can store **only** QString objects, nothing else!

As Neox suggested you should rather store the QImage's url in the list.

Or if your question is about how to serialize the QImage (how to store it to QString which can be added to a QStringList) the answer is QImage's save() method - the official documentation gives a full example in the description of QImage save()

url: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#save-2

code:

```
QImage image;
QByteArray ba;
QBuffer buffer(&ba);
buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
image.save(&buffer, "PNG"); // writes image into ba in PNG format
```

This will save/serialize the given QImage *image* to the QByteArray *ba*.

QByteArray can be simply converted to QString - just use the QString's QByteArray constructor like:

```
QByteArray myByteArray;
QString myStringFromBA(myByteArray);
```